# Rock Paper Scissors Game using if statements

Tags: javascript, game, rock-paper-scissors

I am doing the codecademy course and had to do a rock paper scissors game as a project. Rather than following the instructions I tried Doing it on my own. How I could make the code more efficient?

```
//Only outputs 1-3
const COMPUTERCHOICE = (min=1, max=4) => {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min); };

//Establishes a relation between the numbers and items
console.log('1 = Scissors, 2 = Paper, 3 = Rock\n')

function game(userChoice, computer) {

  if (userChoice === 3 && computer === 1){
    return `User chose ${userChoice}, Computer chose ${computer}, user Wins!`
  }else if (computer === 3 && userChoice === 1){
    return `User chose ${userChoice}, computer chose ${computer}, Computer Wins!`
  }else if (userChoice < computer){
    return `Player chose ${userChoice}, Computer Chose ${computer} User Wins! :D`;
  } else if (userChoice === computer) {
    return `It's a draw!`
  }else {
    return `Player chose ${userChoice}, Computer Chose ${computer} Computer wins :(`;
  };
}

console.log(game(3, COMPUTERCHOICE()))
```

Comment: I like to make a whatBeatsWhat mapping for this scenario. player1 wins if `whatBeatsWhat[p1Choice] === p2Choice`. player2 wins if `whatBeatsWhat[p2Choice] === p1Choice`. Otherwise, it's a tie. I find this to be a simple, readable solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to improve this would be to somehow use a [`switch`](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp) statement in the `game` logic rather than an excessive if-else chain. The `return` statements would replace your `break` statements.

Another small tip would be to use a more descriptive function name like `checkChoice` over `game`. Think about writing code for humans first and computer second. Believe that in a professional environment someone else will eventually look at and maintain your code, and the best way to help them do their job is to make nothing ambiguous.

Finally, reference and use a JavaScript style guide, like [Google's](https://google.github.io/styleguide/jsguide.html).

Comment: How should this code be changed to `switch` statements? Do you mean something like `switch (true) { case userChoice === 3 && computer === 1: ... }`? Could you show the refactored code?

Comment: There are several options, which is why one specific solution is not showcased. This question is also asked in an academic context, so it's best for the student to think and implement rather than copy-paste code that could potentially have bugs.

Answer (score 4):

If you just `return (userChoice % 3 - computer % 3 + 3) % 3` on valid inputs;

- In case of tie, you always get `0`

  - `(0 - 0 + 3) % 3`
  - `(1 - 1 + 3) % 3`
  - `(2 - 2 + 3) % 3`
- In case `userChoice` loses, you always get `1`

  - `(1 - 0 + 3) % 3`
  - `(2 - 1 + 3) % 3`
  - `(0 - 2 + 3) % 3`
- In case `userChoice` wins, you always get `2`

  - `(1 - 2 + 3) % 3`
  - `(2 - 0 + 3) % 3`
  - `(0 - 1 + 3) % 3`

You can use the returned value (`0`, `1`, `2`) to determine which messages to print. You can also use the similar logic on other types of inputs (such as `String`), since `'p' < 'r' < 's'`.